# Database connection is showing error

Tags: php, mysql

I am learner in mySQL.

I have been shown database error whereas server connect is showing successful. I've checked database name and the same is perfect. Tested connect by following code.

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password')

if(!$connect) { echo 'Server connection error';}



$select_db = mysql_select_db('database')

if(!$select_db) { echo 'Server Database error';}

?>
```

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: Apology. Kindly find code

Comment: **mysql_\***  is deprecated and completely removed in PHP 7  use **mysqli_\*** or **PDO** instead

Comment: <?php
    
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password')
    
if(!$connect) { echo 'Server connection error';}
    
    

$select_db = mysql_select_db('database')
    
if(!$select_db) { echo 'Server Database error';}
    
?>

Comment: You need the port, try `localhost:3306` in place of `localhost`

Comment: $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');  $select_db = mysql_select_db('database');  you miss the semicolon in both the statements.

Comment: Thanks Sudheesh, Shailesh, B Desai.

Comment: actually it's database error, connect is working (as first part of code is showing connection working but second part of the above code is not recognizing or connecting to database. Request if can advise possible solutions.     We have deleted current database (after back up) and recreated database by another name, still the same error is occuring

Answer (score -1):

If your error is

```
mysql_* is deprecated and completely removed in PHP 7 use mysqli_* or PDO instead
```

Replace your code to

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if(!$connect) { echo 'Server connection error';}

$select_db = mysqli_select_db('database');
if(!$select_db) { echo 'Server Database error';}
```